# iOS: how to place a control at the center of the parent container?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a control and a container, the container's width is specified firstly. After that I add the control to the container. How to tell the container to place the child control at the center horizontally? I want to specify the y value by myself.

Comment: I calculate the coordinates by myself and seeking for the support by the SDK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The math for that is:

`control.x = (container.width - control.width) / 2`

If this isn't what you were looking for, let me know and I'll try to help!

Comment: You probably want to `floor()` the result lest you get misaligned rendering on non-retina displays.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
childControl.center = parentControl.center;
```

or if you want to center only horizontally:

```
childControl.center = CGPointMake(childControl.center.x,parentControl.center.y);
```

Is easier than doing the math.

**EDIT:**
This only works when the superview has the same size of the parentControl view, to do this within a view that dosen't have the same size of it super view, you can do this:

```
childControl.center = CGPointMake(childControl.center.x,
                                  parentControl.bounds.size.height/2);
```

I haven't tested the line above, but it should work, if it dosen't let me know and I'll test it my self.

Comment: I've found the first way is not really a correct approach because the center's of the parent view and the child view are expressed in different coordinate systems. It only works correctly in cases when the parent view takes up the full screen.

Comment: Yes you are right, the center is calculated based on the superview, sorry about that. I'll add a clarification.